# Use Google Analytics to track bugs?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is it possible to use Google Analytics to keep track of when users receive 404, 401, and other types of errors as well as associate additional data with those reports, such as stack traces?

I've researched around, and [Google Analytics suggests](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86927) using the following to track when users receive 404 errors:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/404.html?page=" + 
 document.location.pathname +  
document.location.search + "&from=" +  
document.referrer);
```

This is great for keeping track of hits, but it doesn't really help in tracking down how the user got to the page in the first place.  Is it possible to associate more informative data with the page view such as a stack trace? Or is Google Analytics not meant to keep track of such data?

Comment: This was flagged as off-topic.  Which SE do you recommend I ask this question on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind you you will receive *some* the way you mentioned - mostly the referring page of the 404.

Concerning your other points: there are **major** security concerns about embedding stack traces into pages shown to the user (which must be the case, because the GA API is client-size JS). It compromises your architecture and other vital security information.

Error logging should be done by a server-side language and basically every language has one, so take your pick - which is probably why GA does not have anything of the kind of features you are asking for.

Comment: While I would agree with you under normal circumstances, the web application will be hosted locally on user's machines, so we don't have access to the error reports generated.

Comment: In that case, I would just setup a central logging gateway file on some server under your control, and then send the logs in an encrypted request. Or really - scratch the encryption - these are their machines anyway :)